# Search 'Input' of Azure Runbook Jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I have a pretty simple issue which perhaps is by-design but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something...

Basically we use a lot of runbooks at my job, and this results in a ton of jobs generated under the automation accounts.  I found I can search based on when the job was created and the name of the runbook, but is there no way to search based on the input parameters of the runbook?

This would help troubleshooting immensely as when someone says "well when were these users created" or "when was this instance upgraded" I can just search for that input param and answer the question quickly.

Perhaps it would be best to log all of the input parameters so then that is searchable via log analytics?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Yes, Currently from Azure Portal there is no way to search based on the input parameters of the runbook. This can be raised as an feature request in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation) UserVoice / feedback forum. Responsible Azure feature / product team would triage and check the feasibility of the feature request and prioritize accordingly.

However, I believe as a workaround we can accomplish your requirement by leveraging Az PowerShell cmdlet [Get-AzAutomationJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/Get-AzAutomationJob?view=azps-4.2.0) as explained in below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the command to use would be something like below:

```
Get-AzAutomationJob -AutomationAccountName "<YourAutomationAccountName>" -ResourceGroupName "<YourAutomationAccountResourceGroupName>" | foreach{Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $_.AutomationAccountName -Id $_.JobId | ?{$_.JobParameters.GetEnumerator().Where({$_.Value -contains "<KeyValueName>"})}}
```

or something like below if you want to validate 2 job parameters (one being key and another being a value)

```
Get-AzAutomationJob -AutomationAccountName "<YourAutomationAccountName>" -ResourceGroupName "<YourAutomationAccountResourceGroupName>" | foreach{Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $_.AutomationAccountName -Id $_.JobId | ?{$_.JobParameters.GetEnumerator().Where({$_.Value -contains "<KeyValueName>"}) -and $_.JobParameters.GetEnumerator().Where({$_.Key -contains "<KeyName>"})}}
```

Similarly you may have to tweak the command a bit to fit your needs.

Comment: Well I upvoted you, but I guess I don't have enough 'reputation' for it to show...

Thanks, this looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: No problem! Glad to know that it was helpful!